# how to align bootstrap dropdowns next to each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to align my li item which bootstrap dropdown how to align it next to each other and i tried everything but seems that nothing is working in my case so what to do
here is my code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg
    navbar-light bg-light">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto se">
          {% for category in category_list %} 
          <li class="nav-item dropdown second">    
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <strong>{{ category.name }}</strong>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
              {% for subcategory in category.our_categories.all %}
              <li><a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">{{ subcategory.name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css for the code

```
 .second{
      display: flex !important;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .secon{
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 2px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because for `.navbar-nav` the default `flex-direction` value is `column`. Make that as `row`

**Just add in css**

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

**OR**

Use `flex-row` helper class for `navbar-nav` in the html as

```
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto se flex-row">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
    .
    .
    .
  </li>
  .
  .
  .
</ul>
```

**Working Example with first solution.**

```css
.second {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.secon {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg
navbar-light bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto se">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink1" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 1</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink1">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink2" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 2</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink2">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink3" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 3</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink3">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink4" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 4</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink4">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink5" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 5</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink5">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown second">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle secon text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink6" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>Category 6</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu cat-drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink6">
        <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="One">One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Two">Two</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Three">Three</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Four">Four</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item cat-item text-white text-center" href="Five">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it does solve the problem but now it stretch the width when open the dropdown how i can fix that

Comment: is it possible to open all dropdown in center o the sceen by the way i tried margin left right auto nothing change

Comment: your code to does stretch the width in mobile view

Comment: Mobile view can be fixed. How should the menu open functionality be worked?

Comment: I want it to be open in the center of screen for all the dropdown

Comment: Is this is your expected behaviour ? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

The [navbar-nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#nav) component is responsive by design. The following quote is from the `navbar-nav` documentation:

> Navigation in navbars will also grow to occupy as much horizontal space as possible to keep your navbar contents securely aligned.

Now that we know they are stacking due to their inherit responsiveness (via Bootstrap), there are **multiple ways to horizontally align items within `navbar-nav`:**

1. **Expand your viewport to ≥992px**. This is being set via `navbar-expand-lg` (or change via option 2 below).
2. **Change `navbar-expand-lg` to `navbar-expand-sm`** which will align the dropdowns horizontally for viewports ≥576px.

   1. **Alternatively, remove responsive behavior by changing `navbar-expand-lg` to `navbar-expand`**. This will ensure they will *always* be horizontally aligned.
3. **Custom CSS classes with greater specificity.** This *wouldn't* be my recommendation but listed as it's a valid option.

**The following showcases the Alternative Option 2 (option 2.1) solution.**

Note that the only change made to your original code is the use of `navbar-expand` instead of `navbar-expand-lg` on `<nav />` element.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand
    navbar-light bg-light">

     <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto se">
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <strong>Category 1</strong>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink1">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 1a</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 1b</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 1c</a>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <strong>Category 2</strong>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink2">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 2a</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 2b</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 2c</a>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink3" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <strong>Category 3</strong>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink3">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 3a</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 3b</a>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'products:product' subcategory.id %}">Category 3c</a>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

 </nav>
```